# Clarification of "distinct" for Combinatorics and counting

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This may be a trivial question but I am quite stuck on interpreting combinatorics vs permutation in some cases. For example, suppose the following question:

"Seven different gifts are to be distributed among 10 children. How many distinct results are possible if no child is to receive more than one gift?"

For this one, I interpreted it as being a combinatorics question here as I had thought that order does not matter here, so in that case, we have 7 spots and it does not matter in what type of arrangement we put them in, as long as child 1 receives the gift 1-10, then that would be it. I know that generally we use combinatorics when we don't want to double count but I am not sure why the answer had that it is $10*9*8*7*6*5*4$.

Comment: The kids care which gift they get. The situation is different if $7$ identical candies are distributed among $7$ kids, no more than one per kid. Then all that matters is which kids are chosen to receive a candy.

Comment: I get $10*9*8*7*6*5*4$, don't see how you get the factor of $3$ at the end. Are you sure you copied the question and answer exactly?

Comment: That was a typo, my bad. I edited it out to get rid of the 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamental questions you should always ask yourself in solving a problem where multiple choices have to be made from a set.  In this case there are $10$ children and you are choosing $7$ of them to receive gift 1, gift 2 and so on, and you must ask:

- can the same child be chosen more than once?
- does the order of choosing the children matter?

For this question:

- can the same child be chosen more than once? - NO, because it is stated that "no child is to receive more than one gift" - a child can be chosen once, or not at all, but not more than once;
- does the order of choosing the children matter? - YES, because the gifts are all different.  So choosing Anna to get gift 1 and Billy to get gift 2 is clearly a different outcome from choosing Billy first to get gift 1 and then Anna to get gift 2.

The case where repetition is not possible and order matters is called a **permutation**.  So you want the number of permutations of $7$ children from $10$, which is
$$P(10,7)={}^{10}P_7=10\times9\times8\times7\times6\times5\times4\ .$$

Answer (score 2):

The key difference is that the gifts are different, so it matters **who gets what gift** and not just **who gets gifts**.

Consider this similar, simplified case. Say we have 7 identical gifts and 7 girls and each girl gets one. Clearly there's only one way to do this.

However, what if instead we have 7 different gifts, like we do in this problem? Then it's not just a question of who gets gifts (indeed, every girl in this situation gets exactly one gift), but who gets what gift -- who gets the lego set, who gets the video games, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I just included a follow up question, I understand it much clearer

Answer (score 0):

If we think about it in a "combinational" way, we will have it like this:
7! * (10C7)
7! Is the gifts distributed.
And 10C7 is the group of 7 kids from those 10.
And 7! * (10C7)= 7! * [10!/(7! * 3!)]= 10!/3!= 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4. The result you had.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).